# Question on existential sentences

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

A sentence is called existential if it is of the form $\exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n \ \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where $\phi$ is quantifier free.

We know that (see Chang-Keisler "Model Theory", Proposition 5.2.2)

**Theorem.** If every existential sentence that holds in $\mathfrak{A}$ also holds in $\mathfrak{B}$, then $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphically embeddable in some elementary extension of $\mathfrak{B}$.

Suppose that we have a theory $T$ such that all its models agree on existential sentences. By the previous theorem, starting with two models $\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{B} \models T$, we can prove that for any $n > 0$, $\mathfrak{A}$ is $n$-sandwiched by model $\mathfrak{B}$. To see this, notice that since $\mathfrak{B} \models T$ and all models of $T$ agree on existential sentences, we have that $\mathfrak{B}$ can be isomorphically embedded in some elementary extension $\mathfrak{A}_0$ of $\mathfrak{A}$. This means that $\mathfrak{B} \subseteq \mathfrak{A}_0$. Now $\mathfrak{A}_0 \models T$, since $\mathfrak{A} \models T$ and $\mathfrak{A} \prec \mathfrak{A}_0$. So $\mathfrak{A}_0$ can be isomorphically embedded in some elementary extension $\mathfrak{B}_1$ of $\mathfrak{B}$. So we have $\mathfrak{B} \subseteq \mathfrak{A}_0 \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_1$. We can go on like this for infinitely many steps.

Is this argument wrong? If not, does this mean that every theory $T$ such that all its models agree on existential sentences, is also $\Pi_2$ (and actually even $\Pi_{2n}$) complete? Doesn't ZFC satisfy the above condition as $T$?

Note : **Theorem (added).** (Change-Keisler Proposition 5.2.5) If there are models $\mathfrak{A}', \mathfrak{B}'$ such that $\mathfrak{B} \subseteq \mathfrak{A}' \subseteq \mathfrak{B}'$, $\mathfrak{B} \prec \mathfrak{B}'$ and $\mathfrak{A} \prec \mathfrak{A}'$, then every $\Pi_2$ sentence holding in $\mathfrak{A}$ also holds in $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: Your argument seems correct.  Perhaps I am missing something easy, but why does this argument imply your theory is $\Pi_2$?  By the way, ZFC does not satisfy your condition because it has some models that satisfy Con(ZFC) and some don't, and $\neg\mathrm{Con(ZFC)}$ is, in a sense, existential.

Comment: The existence of $n$-sandwiches implies that every $\Pi_{2n}$ sentence that holds in $\mathfrak{A}$ also holds in $\mathfrak{B}$ (see Chang-Keisler Proposition 5.2.7), which is not seem reasonable. Now for the case of ZFC, the existential sentences do not have restricted quantifiers, they just have existential quantifiers. These are very simple sentences actually. The sentence expressing the consistency of ZFC must have a large quantifier rank, i.e. it must be $\Sigma_n$ for some large $n$. E.g. an existential sentence is $\exists x \exists y (x \in y \wedge x \neq y \wedge x \notin y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Doesn't Proposition 5.2.5 only imply your theory is complete for $\Pi_2$ sentences (rather than your theory being $\Pi_2$ axiomatized)?

Comment: Yes you are correct, we actually need one more theorem from Chang-Keisler (Theorem 5.2.6) to get that it is $\Pi_2$ axiomatized. It says that if $T$ is preserved under 1-sandwiches, i.e. if $\mathfrak{A} \models T$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ is sandwiched by $\mathfrak{B}$ implies $\mathfrak{B} \models T$, then $T$ has a set of $\Pi_2$ axioms.

Comment: How do you show that your theory is preserved under 1-sandwiches?  By the way, I see what you meant about ZFC now.  So I withdraw my claim in my first comment.  It is not clear to me whether all models of ZFC satisfy the same existential sentences, but it seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Indeed you are right, $T$ may not be preserved under 1-sandwiches. I got carried away on this one. I have to edit my question. For the existential sentences of ZFC now. Every model of ZFC is infinite. So let us take a quantifier free formula, e.g. $(x_1 \in x_2 \wedge x_2 \notin x_3 \wedge x_1 \neq x_3)$. For such formulas, it seems to me, that we can always find sets (finite ones actually) that witness if they hold or not.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about ZFC.  I didn't notice it before, and it was instructive for me to write out a proper proof myself.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a problem with your argument. When you say that $\mathfrak A_0$ can be embedded in an elementary extension of $\mathfrak B$, it means that there is an elementary extension $\mathfrak B_1$ of $\mathfrak B$ and an embedding $f : \mathfrak A_0 \to \mathfrak B_1$. Then you say that we can identify $\mathfrak A_0$ with $f(\mathfrak A_0)$ and get $\mathfrak B \subseteq \mathfrak A_0 \subseteq \mathfrak B_1$. The problem is that you don't know what $f$ does to $\mathfrak B$. In other words $f(\mathfrak B)$ might not be an elementary substructure of $\mathfrak B_1$.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. This is a good lesson not to blindly identify structures, that are related by an isomorphism.